# Java can't find jackson jar file

Tags: java, jar, jackson, classpath

I need to use jackson to handle some JSON in my code. I wrote a simple test class to get it working.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

I placed `jackson-databind-2.9.9.1.jar` in `/dirwherejarresides/jdk/jre/lib/ext`.

I am able to compile the class with no issues, and produce `Test.class`.

```
javac Test.java
```

However, I can't seem to get java find the jar & execute the class.

```
java -cp "/dirwhereclassresides/java" Test                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:37)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:291)
        at Test.main(Test.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 3 more
```

I tried adding the path where the jar resides, but I get the same error.

```
java -cp "/dirwhereclassresides/java:/dirwherejarresides/jdk/jre/lib/ext/jackson-databind-2.9.9.1.jar" Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:37)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:291)
        at Test.main(Test.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 3 more
```

What do I need to do to get java to see the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson library is split into several jar-modules that declare dependencies between each other. For example: `jackson-databind` depends on `jackson-annotations` and `jackson-core`.

The `jackson-databind-*.jar` does not actually contain a class for `JsonView` annotation that you get the exception about. It is placed in the `jackson-annotations-*.jar` file. But to be able to parse a JSON with Jackson you will definitely need `jackson-core-*.jar` as well.

Btw, your second way to pass a class path is more correct, you need to list all jar-files your class depends on in the `-cp` parameter split by colon on the Unix/Linux systems. E.g.

```
$ java -cp ".:/pathtojackson/jackson-databind-2.9.9.1.jar:/pathtojackson/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar:/pathtojackson/jackson-annotations-2.9.9.jar" Test
```

You can also use star-expressions in `-cp` parameter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/2288384

Comment: That worked! I was missing the core & annotation jars.

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining about `annotation/JsonView` and seems like it found `jackson data-bind`. Since you are not using maven, I suspect `jackson-core` which is a transitive dependency of data-bind, is not injected.

Try adding `jackson-core` into your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Often ClassNotFoundException are a side effect of you having the two of the same packages with different versions. Print out a dependency tree and see that there is not two versions of the same dependency loaded.

Comment: How do I do that?